# My for-loop won't iterate over a string in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have to check what dates are missing for equity options and I want to do this with a for-loop. However

> "'(slice(0, 155, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key"

shows up as error and I can't figure out why.

First it was a `datetime64[ns]` type and I've already tried to convert it to a string. However, it didn't seem to help. Here is my code :

```
def days(data, alldays):
days = np.zeros((len(data),1))
companies = ["AAPL", "AXP", "BA", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX", "DIS", "DJX", "GS", "HD", "IBM", "INTC", "JNJ", \
    "JPM", "KO", "MCD", "MMM", "MRK", "MSFT", "NKE", "PFE", "PG", "TRV", "UNH", "UTX", "V", "VZ", "WBA", "WMT", "XOM"]
d = {}
for i, firm in enumerate(data):
    firms = data[i]
    days[i] = len(firms.date.unique())
    firmdays = firms.date.unique()
    counter = 0
    if days[i] < 3730:
        print(firms.ticker.unique(), len(firms), days[i])
    elif days[i] < len(alldays) and days[i]>=3730:
        d[companies[i]] = np.zeros((582348,6))
        breakpoint()
        for j in range(3733):
            breakpoint()
            if alldays[j] not in  firmdays:
                breakpoint()
                print(firms.ticker.unique(), alldays[j])
                for k, data in enumerate(np.zeros((582348,6))):
                    d[companies[i]][k:k+155,:] = firms[k-156 - counter*156:k-1- 156*counter,:]
                counter = counter +1
            else:
                for k, data in enumerate(np.zeros((582348,6))):
                    d[companies[i]][k:k+155,:] = firms[k- counter*156:k+155 - 156*counter,:]
    print(firms.ticker.unique(), len(firms), days[i])
return days
```

It gives an error at line `"if alldays[j] not in firmdays:"`, namely

```
'(slice(0, 155, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Comment: what's the value of `alldays[j]` and it's type?

Comment: Sorry, the code is a bit lacking. alldays is currently a datetime64[ns] type which basically just gives the date, alldays[0] gives: numpy.datetime64('1996-04-01:00:00.000000000')

Comment: and whats the value of `alldays[j]` when the error occurs? Or does it fail on the first iteration (when j=0)

Comment: I'm a bit new in Python, but I think it's 'ndarray object of numpy module'. The if statement indeed already fails for j=0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, the problem seems more with the use of the slice notation (on part before = sign) on that line:

```
d[companies[i]][k:k+155,:] = firms[k- counter*156,:]
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6203472

Comment: Thanks, this might be wrong as well. However, in my real code I have breakpoint() after the if statement, and it doesn't reach this breakpoint due to this line.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace that comes with the error then